# MaTeX bug when combined with a transparency

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, opacity, matex

Works fine:

```
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[1], Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]},Inset[MaTeX["P", Magnification -> 4], {.5, .5, .5}] }]
```

Works not fine:

```
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.5], Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]},Inset[MaTeX["P", Magnification -> 4], {.5, .5, .5}] }]
```

[image]

Comment: If you think that there is a bug in MaTeX, you really should report it directly to me. However, this is not a bug in MaTeX. It is a bug in Mathematica. Take e.g. this FilledCurve example from the documentation and use it instead of the MaTeX function: `pts = {{0, 1}, {-1, -(1/2)}, {1, -(1/2)}}; Graphics[FilledCurve[{{Line[2 pts]}, {Line[pts]}}]]`. It seems all FilledCurves with holes are affected.

Comment: You should report this bug to Wolfram Research.

Comment: Thanks, reported.